# Drawable as styleable and how themes are selected

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-theme, android-styles

In this code [ToolbarWidgetWrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.1_r6/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java#104)
I see that the `Drawable` is defined as styleable.
I tried to find what is that drawable and I found definitions such as:

```
res/res/values/themes.xml:          <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
res/res/values/themes_holo.xml:     <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
res/res/values/themes_holo.xml:     <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>
res/res/values/themes_holo.xml:     <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
res/res/values/styles.xml:          <item name="collapseIcon">?attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>
res/res/values/themes_material.xml: <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_material</item>
res/res/values/themes_material.xml: <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_material</item>
```

It seems that this kind of definition ensures that the icon corresponds to the app's theme and I see the icons are completely different in each definition.
Is that right? And if so, I was wondering how exactly the corresponding file is being selected? Does it depend only on some app configuration about the theme?
Is there a case that none of these would be selected?